# Excel VBA Application.iferror() is not handling a div/0 error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple UDF program.  I have one line in it, that divides two numbers. I am needing to have the IFERROR return a value when it gets an error.
In my program, the Testrange(1) contains 90, and testrange(4) contains 0.
My UDF crashes and returns a Value error.

Here is my code.

```
Function myTestRange(TestRange As Range, myvol As Integer, myType As String) As Variant

    myTestRange = Application.IfError(TestRange(1) / TestRange(4), 4567)

End Function
```

I was looking at Microsoft's page on the IFERROR function and it seems to list that a div/0 is one of the errors that it handles.

Thanks for any help on this.
Rich

Comment: fundamental issue is that IFERROR is a worksheet statment so it will identify if a 'CELL' has an error. Not if the math has an error.

Comment: TestRange(1) / TestRange(4) will generate a run time error (divide-by-0) - "IfError" does not fix or handle this this, its of little use in VBA.  Either test for 0 or use error handling.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but check the following link and let me know if you think I am missing something: it appears to say that it will work.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-iferror-method-excel

Comment: The error occurs before anything is passed to `IfError`. It should work if you use for example `Application.IfError(Application.Quotient(TestRange(1), TestRange(4)), 4567)`

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is that VBA will trap the error itself before the function gets called.  For example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError((0 / 0), "no good")
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

will die even before the function gets called, so the MsgBox never gets displayed.  Even:

```
Sub qwerty2()
    On Error Resume Next
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError((0 / 0), "no good")
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

runs to completion because the `OnError` statement disables VBA's preemptive error handling, but `IfError()` does not return anything.

You need something like:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    a = 2
    b = 7
    On Error Resume Next
         If IsError(b / a) Then
           x = "no good"
        Else
            x = b / a
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

which returns valid information even if both **a** and **b** are zero.

Answer (score 1):

What about using if statements.

```
Function myTestRange(TestRange As Range, myvol As Integer, myType As String) As Variant
    If tesrange(4) = 0 Then
        myTestRange = 4567
    Else
        myTestRange = TestRange(1) / TestRange(4)
    End If
    'myTestRange = Application.IfError(TestRange(1) / TestRange(4), 4567)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In my case, it will be quite a bit more complex, since my data has the probability of many of the values being zero.  In these cases, I do need the value of 0 to be returned.  Please check out the following link and let me know what you think. It seems to show that it should work.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-iferror-method-excel